# Is it possible to create groups of objects in Access 2010 forms?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have a form with 3 option buttons, and about 50 labels, textboxes, and buttons. Is there a way I can group some of these objects so that way when I select an option, some of the objects get disabled or enabled and I only have to use vba to say which group is enabled or disabled? Or will I have to write vba for each object and have 1000 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this kind of problem with custom collections in Access. I've written at length on that here:

[How to Use Controls Collection in Access 2003 and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917981/how-to-use-controls-collection-in-access-2003-and-vba/1932103#1932103)